# how to use multiple checkboxes with php and pagination

Tags: php, pagination, checkbox

Hello i have the code below to paginate my data, I also have some checkboxes which to adjust the results shown. The problem Im having is that it works fine when I have everything on the 1 page but when the results paginate the pagination will not show at the bottom it just shows 14 results and thats it. here is my code

```
 if(isset($_POST['criteria']) && !empty($_POST['criteria'])){ 
 foreach($_POST['criteria'] as $key=>$value){ 

 // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
 $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['criteria']);

 //get the function
 include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/script/pagination-functions.php');    
 $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
 $limit = 14;
 $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

// Convert the array into a string.
 $criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);
 if(!$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE exercise IN ('$criteria') ORDER BY long ASC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}"))
 {
echo "Cannot parse query";
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
echo "No records found";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

       echo "".$row['title'] ."<br>
             ".$row['description'] ."";
        }
         echo "<div class=\"new-pagination\">";
        echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Here is my pagination script

```
     function pagination($query, $per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '?'){    

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total = $row['num'];
    $adjacents = "1"; 

    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;   

    $firstPage = 1;
    $prev = ($page == 1)?1:$page - 1; 

    $prev = $page - 1;                          
    $next = $page + 1;
    $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;


    $pagination = "";


    if($lastpage >  1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<ul class=\"pagination1\">";

                if ($page == 1)
  {
  $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">First</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Prev</a></li>"; 
  }
  else
   {
  $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$firstPage\">First</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$prev\">Prev</a></li>"; 
  }



                $pagination .= "<li class=\"details\">Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))

        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
        else
         $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>";                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
         if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))       
        {
         for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>";                 
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">... </li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>";       
        }
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=1\">1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=2\">2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">...</li>";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>";                 
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">..</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>";       
            }
            else
            {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=1\">1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=2\">2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">..</li>";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter 
                 $lastpage;             
                 $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
                    else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$next\">Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}&page=$lastpage\">Last</a></li>";
        }else{
            $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Last</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
    }


    return $pagination;
}
```

also would I need to store data of the selected checkboxes to get the results to hold for the next page. If anyone could give me any help or point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

Comment: Your question is much better if you improved the title..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the code is complete, the `$statement` variable is undefined, so the SQL in `pagination` function has invalid syntax, as the `$query` is empty.

Also note that you have no operator in the third expression of the last `for` loop. So the code does not even compile.

Do you have warnings enabled in PHP? Probably not, otherwise you would get some and they would like guide you to solution. Please enable them and share. You will get better asnwers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin, I'm completley new with php, how do I enable warnings and also what do you mean with no operator in the third expression of the last for loop. Sorry im pretty new to php

Comment: I have solved my code and it seems to all be workoing now the only problem is that when I select more then one checkbox the rest of the page after the script cuts off and does not show any ideas why, it works fine if just one check box is selected.

Comment: Would be nice if you share your solution. Thanks. Otherwise this question is pointless and should be removed.

Comment: Sorry Martin, All I done was remove the for each loop and changed  checkboxes to <input type="checkbox" name="groupname[]" id="value" value="value" /> and included $statment inside the query line.